Hosting subdomains on separate server

I am looking at a project where the existing domain is live and functional.
I am proposing to use subdomains such as app.example.com and op.example.com for clarity.

Are there any disadvantages in using the (several) subdomains on a separate host with a redirection from the main site to this host?
This way I wont disturb the current domain in any way.

Its unclear what you are meaning by "disadvantages".  This is commonly accepted as OK, and the SEO tests my SEO experts group have done say that using subdomains don't have a meaningful impact on SEO.

In general, if everything is organized properly, there shouldn't be any serious problems.
Speaking of the SEO component, it's important to consider that search engines view subdomains as separate websites. Accordingly, their authorities will differ.
And the second point is the interaction between subdomains and the main domain.
If the subdomains need to interact with the main site, you may need to set up data exchange and consider security nuances.
For example, sessions, cookies, or API requests.
You'll need to configure CORS and handle cookies between different hosts since browsers often block such interactions by default.

Something feels off here! Everything should be organized, but it’s not always that easy. People underestimate how search engines see subdomains. Each one has its own vibe, and their authority can be all over the place, which is confusing.
Plus, don’t forget about how subdomains and the main site talk to each other! If we don’t set up CORS and cookies right, we’re asking for trouble. Are we really going to deal with these same headaches again? We need to be more on top of this!
